# What uniform does Frank Regan Wear?

Tags: blue-bloods

In Blue Bloods, Frank wears a uniform on occasion. In real life, the NYPD commissioner is a civilian and doesn't have a uniform. So, either in the canon of blue bloods, the PC has a uniform or he is wearing the uniform of his past days as a police officer. Is it ever explained in canon if Frank's uniform is not that of the PC, but a hold-over from when he was an officer? I noticed he wears 4 stars which denote the chief of department, a position he held before being appointed PC.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The NYPD Police Commissioner does not wear a uniform.

In the show, **it's purely for effect**.

> Tom Selleck might have read Bill Bratton’s book, but he still managed to get one thing wrong about his character’s role. Frank Reagan can sometimes be found an all-black uniform on Blue Bloods. **But that’s not quite true to real life**. Bratton told him so at Elio’s, according to Page Six.
>
> “In New York, the commissioner is a civilian,” explained telecaster Rikki Klieman. “In L.A., the police chief is a peace officer who reports to a board of commissioners.” So the police commissioner in New York doesn’t wear a uniform every day. But who doesn’t want to see Tom Selleck in a uniform?
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/blue-bloods-how-do-real-police-officers-feel-about-the-show.html/)</sup>

Essentially, the production company thought it looked good.